# I am trying to store user input as JSON array in local storage and displaying them in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, json, web-deployment

I am trying to store user input as JSON in local storage with the help of html forms and then trying to display them in a html table.

I can see the values getting stored in the local storage with the inspect element tool, but something is going wrong and my values are not showing on the table.

I tried doing it in different ways too but nothing worked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Putting User Input into JS Objects</title>
    <style>
        .formBox{
            padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
        }
        table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="formBox">
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="FirstName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="formBox">
            <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="LastName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="formBox">
            <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
            <select name="gender" id="gender" >
                <option value="Male" selected disabled>Select Gender</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="prefer not to say">Prefer Not to Say</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="formBox">
            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <input type="number" id="age" min="1" placeholder="Age"/>
        </div>
        <div class="formBox">
            <label for="specialization">Specialization:</label>
            <select name="specialization" id="specialization" >
                <option value="Not Selected" selected disabled>Specialization</option>
                <option value="Database Programmer">Database Programmer</option>
                <option value="Web Developer">Web Developer</option>
                <option value="Software Programmer">Software Programmer</option>
                <option value="Network Engineer">Network Engineer</option>
                
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="formBox">
            <label for="exp">Experience</label>
            <input type="number" id="exp" min="1" placeholder="Experience"/>
        </div>
        <div class="formBox">
            <label for="achi">Achievements</label>
            <input type="text" id="achi" placeholder="Achievements"/>
        </div>
        <div class="formBox">
            <button onclick="Submit()">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="msg">
            <pre></pre>
        </div>
    </form>
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
          <th>F. Name:</th>
          <th>L. Name:</th>
          <th>Gender:</th>
          <th>Age:</th>
          <th>Specialization:</th>
          <th>Experience:</th>
          <th>Achievements:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id ="tbl_data">
        </tr>
        <tr>
      </table>
<script>
    var taskData = [];
var i = null;
function Submit() {
    if (taskData.length > 0) {
        var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
        var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
        var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
        var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        var specialization = document.getElementById('specialization').value;
        var experience = document.getElementById('exp').value;
        var achievement = document.getElementById('achi').value;
        const obj = { "fname": fname, "lname": lname, "gender": gender, "age": age, "specialization": specialization, "exp": experience, "achi": achievement }
        var stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"));
        stored.push(obj);
    }
    var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var specialization = document.getElementById('specialization').value;
    var experience = document.getElementById('exp').value;
    var achievement = document.getElementById('achi').value;
    const obj = { "fname": fname, "lname": lname, "gender": gender, "age": age, "specialization": specialization, "exp": experience, "achi": achievement }
    taskData.push(obj);

    localStorage.setItem("task", JSON.stringify(taskData));
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("task");

    if (i == null) {
        i = 0;
    }

    for (i = i; i < taskData.length; ++i) {

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = i + 1;
        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = taskData[i].fname;
        row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = taskData[i].lname;
        row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = taskData[i].gender;
        row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = taskData[i].age;
        row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = taskData[i].specialization;
        row.insertCell(6).innerHTML = taskData[i].exe;
        row.insertCell(7).innerHTML = taskData[i].achi;
        i = i;
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of your exact error, but you can easily set and display an item with functions from a user's input here is the code -

```
function saveData() {
    var userinput = prompt("Enter anything")
    localStorage.setItem("userinput", JSON.stringify(userinput));
}
function loadData() {
    var stored = localStorage.getItem('userinput');
    if (stored == null) {
        document.write("No data has been saved yet")
    } else {
        document.write('Saved Object: ' + JSON.parse(stored));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: You don't have an element with id "result" in HTML... so nothing is displayed. Create `<div id="result"></div>` anywhere in your HTML.

Second: You are calling `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("task");` inside `function Submit()`. Move that above or below function.

Here is working solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Local Storage Persistence Testing</title>
    <style>
        form { padding: 0.5rem 2rem; }
        table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
        td, th { border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Form elements -->
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="FirstName"/>
        <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="LastName"/>
        <select name="gender" id="gender" >
            <option value="Male" selected disabled>Select Gender</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="prefer not to say">Prefer Not to Say</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" id="age" min="1" placeholder="Age"/>
        <select name="specialization" id="specialization" >
            <option value="Not Selected" selected disabled>Specialization</option>
            <option value="Database Programmer">Database Programmer</option>
            <option value="Web Developer">Web Developer</option>
            <option value="Software Programmer">Software Programmer</option>
            <option value="Network Engineer">Network Engineer</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" id="exp" min="1" placeholder="Experience"/>
        <input type="text" id="achi" placeholder="Achievements"/>
        <button onclick="LocalDataStore()">Add</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Table data display -->
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
          <th>F. Name:</th>
          <th>L. Name:</th>
          <th>Gender:</th>
          <th>Age:</th>
          <th>Specialization:</th>
          <th>Experience:</th>
          <th>Achievements:</th>
        </tr>
      </table>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        // Load table data from local storage
        if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"))){
            var sData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"));
            for (i = 0; i < sData.length; i++) {
                var row = document.getElementById("table").insertRow();
                row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = sData[i].fname;
                row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = sData[i].lname;
                row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = sData[i].gender;
                row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = sData[i].age;
                row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = sData[i].specialization;
                row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = sData[i].exp;
                row.insertCell(6).innerHTML = sData[i].achi;
            }
        }

        // Store data to local storage
        function LocalDataStore() {
            var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
            var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
            var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
            var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
            var specialization = document.getElementById('specialization').value;
            var experience = document.getElementById('exp').value;
            var achievement = document.getElementById('achi').value;
            var taskData = {
                "fname": fname,
                "lname": lname,
                "gender": gender,
                "age": age,
                "specialization": specialization,
                "exp": experience,
                "achi": achievement
            };
            if (!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"))) {
                localStorage.setItem("task", JSON.stringify([taskData]));
            } else {
                var localStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"));
                localStorageData.push(taskData);
                localStorage.setItem("task", JSON.stringify(localStorageData));
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I followed the above mentioned steps, now when i click on button add the values appear in the table just for a second and then disappear and values are showing above the form in a json format.

Comment: Check solution in my edited answer